# Data not being sent to the table during a successful database connection

Tags: php, mysql

I have created the database and the table and the connection with the database was successful but the data is not being sent to the database

```
<?php

$mysqli = mysqli_connect('****************', '***************', '*************', '******posts');
if ($mysqli) {
    echo "conn established";
} else {
    echo "conn failed";
}

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $one = "one";
    $two = "two";
    $three = "three";
    $four = "four";
    $five = "five";
    $push = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO articles 
        (id,title,thumbnail,upvotes,views,url) 
        VALUES ('$one','$two','$three','$four','$five')");
    if ($push) {
        echo "---------pushed----------";
    } else {
        echo "-----not pushed----";
    }
}
```

Comment: `mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or die(mysqli_error());`  please check what error are you getting?

Comment: @DilipHirapara but i dont have $query in my code, should i replace push with query?

Comment: Let me know error so that I can post the answer for it.

Comment: is your table name and columns correct ,where is your html ?

Comment: everything is correct and thats what driving me crazy

Comment: conn established
Error: INSERT INTO articles (id,title,thumbnail,upvotes,views,url2) VALUES ('one','two','three','4','5',)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 2

Answer (score -1):

checkout this code

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "nepalroute";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

 if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $one = "one";
    $two = "two";
    $three = "three";
    $four = "four";
    $five = "five";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO articles (id,title,thumbnail,upvotes,views,url) 
    VALUES ('$one','$two','$three','$four','$five')";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }

 }

 ?>
```

Comment: didnt work brother

Comment: its not even showing the errors

Comment: does it print any error

Comment: what is the name of your button from where you submit the form

Comment: your button name should be like ````<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>````

Comment: <button name="submit" value="submit">submit</button>

Comment: check ````<form method = "post"  action =""> ````

Comment: also those are true

Comment: now it says conn establishedError: INSERT INTO articles (id,title,thumbnail,upvotes,views,url2) VALUES ('one','two','three','4','5',)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 2

Comment: after ````'$five',```` replace with ````VALUES ('$one','$two','$three','$four','$five')";````

Comment: you might have extra ````, ```` after $five

Answer (score -1):

Use this function for run query

mysqli_query($conn, $sql)

Comment: conn established
Error: INSERT INTO articles (id,title,thumbnail,upvotes,views,url2) VALUES ('one','two','three','4','5',)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 2